# Hyperlinks Rendered in PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf, telerik-reporting

I have a report that is created using Telerik Reporing 2010.
You have the ability to export to PDF.
One of the cells contains a standard hyperlink that when viewed from the report view works fine
The cell contains this simple link

```
<a href=”http://site.com”>link</a>
```

What I would like to be able to do is maintain the hyperlink functionality when the report is rendered to PDF.
Im assuming PDF requires something more than just HTML to render a link ?
Any help is most appreciated

Thanks

truegilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperlinks in PDF Telerik Reports are not currently supported. See this [forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/how-to-display-field-in-hyperlink.aspx) on the Telerik site for more information.

There isn't anything that you can do to fix this. When the PDF report is generated Telerik need to implement a feature that converts your HTML hyperlink into a hotspot annotation in the PDF.